# Jenkins Slack Integration to set reminders

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, slack-api, slack

I am trying to set Slack reminders via a Jenkins job. We are using the Slack plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/slack) which seems to work great for direct messages, but I am unable to set reminders. Running the /remind command in Slack, obviously, works. But when I try to use the same command as a Custom Message, it doesn't. Following is what I have set currently, but it doesn't seem to work ie no reminders are getting set.

[image: Jenkins Post Build Action]

Comment: Have you tried escaping the slash in front of **remind**?

Comment: Yes, I tried that

Answer (score 0):

The Custom Message field in the Slack plugin is just for messages - it is not parsed by Slack for Slack slash commands that are ordinarily typed by a Slack user in Slack's message entry field.

The Slack plugin appears to label the contents of the Custom Message field as text and wrap other info around it in order to provide the green/amber/red indicator that is displayed to the left of the message, along with the build # and Success/Fail etc. notification.

See https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting

Comment: Take a look at "Slack apps".